# Android - Notification isn't appeared

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create Notification using AppCompat inside Fragment.
I create see nothing.

Code:

```
private void createNotification()
{
    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ymk_ya_logo)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentTitle("notify")
            .setContentText("test");

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManager.notify(777, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your last bit to this instead:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```